# Dolphin in a pool - using Kolmogorov's forward equations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

**Problem**

> A dolphin swims between 3 different pools, A B and C. The time is
>   spend in each pool, before going to the next one, is Exp(1/2). The
>   possible ways for it to travel is A to B. B to C. C to A. C to B. When
>   in C, it choses B or A randomly with the same probability.
>
> Given the dolphin starts in pool X at time 0 define $P_{XY}(t)$ as
>   "the probabilitythat the dolphin is in pool Y at time t".
>
> Find  $P_{AA} (t)$ $P_{AB} (t)$ $P_{AC} (t)$.

**Attempt**

Since we have a finite space {A,B,C } I use chapman kolmogorov's forward equations, and obtain

$$P'_{AA} (t) = 1 \cdot (1-e^{-2t})-2 \cdot (e^{-2t})$$

$$P'_{AB} (t) = 2 \cdot e^{-2t} + 1 \cdot 2t^2e^{-2t} -2 \cdot 2te^{-2t}$$

$$P'_{AC} (t) = 2 \cdot 2te^{-2t} - 2 \cdot 2t^2e^{-2t}$$

where the third line is not really needed. And of course, $P_{AA} (t)+P_{AB} (t)+P_{AC} (t)=1$.

**Question**

Now we have everything needed to solve the equations, correct?